# How to change alert message when error occured after sign up in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, parse-platform

I would like to change the error message that comes with the alert, when an error occur when the user signs in.
I tried with :

```
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didFailToSignUpWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"me" message:error.debugDescription preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Failed to sign up... %@ ", error.debugDescription);

}
```

the log appears well, but the alert controller is still the old one.
For the record, when the email is already taken, it says "the email MyName ..." instead of "the email MyEmail... is already taken".

Would you know how to do this?

Edit :
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you saying the alert view isn't displaying what you expect?

Comment: @AdamPro13 I wanted to customize the text in the alert, for 1/use a custom text and 2/ correct the current text, which is showing the name instead of the email in the alert message (please see my edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, my email address is showing up in place of the MyName, you have something else going on there.

Additionally, I have been playing around with this for 1.6 and found the same results as [this answer 2 years ago](https://www.parse.com/questions/customizing-error-responses-of-pfloginviewcontroller-and-pfsignupcontroller) and an updated comment from another Parse developer [here 1 year ago](https://parse.com/questions/override-default-pfloginviewcontroller-login-error). I guess they just don't find it a priority for us right now. This doesn't make my answer right, someone else may have found a solution, but I subclassed the signUpViewController and everything where you have access to `self.signUpView.emailField.text` to pass in your UIAlertController. Also, nothing is in their [changelog](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) about it. So my answer, is, it's not directly editable at this time, but don't feel like it's the right answer. It simply looks like if you want this functionality you will have to go with either localized strings or creating your own sign up /login view controllers where you have access to the `UITextFields` text and where you can use whatever alert you wish, custom or otherwise

Comment: Thanks, edit: found it here : https://github.com/hendrikswan/motioncasts-parse-push/blob/master/vendor/Parse.framework/Resources/Localizable.strings ////// previous message : Does it mean, I just have to create a Localizable.strings file and it will override the text used in the alert message? About the subclass, I don't understand how you would do it. The aim is to change the text in the alert, it appears as in my edit (the email is replaced by the name, but in the log, it is different, it appears well).

Comment: Right I was just saying I tested it that route so it would save you some time. That's why the only options I would personally go with is the localized strings or creating a custom login/signup VC. But yes that's a valuable resource. Parse is open source which is awesome I love that. Additionally if you ever have any stumpers the developers no longer use SO as a resource they use a Google groups forum where they answer questions. Will post link when I get to a computer

Comment: heres the link @Paul https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers they are extremely active in answering questions, specifically Hector. But as of right now, looks like you will have to stick with localized strings or creating your own VCs

Comment: thanks @soulshined, I opened a new thread in the Google group, I tried with localization but the text is still the same one (I pasted the line from the link above in a Localizable.strings file, in 2 languages). I will see if I find an answer on the Google Group.

Comment: @Paul reviewing the docs today for the giggles and stumbled upon this : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-string/iOS specifically the last point, it talks about how to customize variables. Reminded me of this question you had, not sure if it's resolved on your end but it's worth the share

Answer (score 1):

the message is error.debugDescription. if you want, you can change it to something else, whatever you want

Comment: thanks, both of them would be good actually ;-)  I edited my post to show the error message.