# how to change Parse system error codes?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, error-handling

I was wondering if anyone knew how I can alter, or change the error code that comes from Parse within my Alert View. When the login parameters are incorrect it sends the following message :

[image]

that message is so generic, I want to change it to something different. How do i do this?

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/override-default-pfloginviewcontroller-login-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change alert message when error occured after sign up in Parse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484027/how-to-change-alert-message-when-error-occured-after-sign-up-in-parse)

Comment: how do i edit the error.debugDescription? @soulshined

Comment: with localized strings as the examples go through

Comment: forgive me, I'm knew to iOS, who do i localize a sting? whats that procedure? @soulshined

Comment: its okay, but you should see the examples in the either of the links I provided above. They both are fantastic starts, and spot on reflections of your end goal

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what this guy did in the answer, for my login https://www.parse.com/questions/customizing-error-responses-of-pfloginviewcontroller-and-pfsignupcontroller .. but i do not know how to implement a localizable string is what I'm saying. how do i access the parse code and change it with a localizable string @soulshined

Comment: Note Hectors response : `You can provide a Localizable.strings file` in other words you have to set up your app for localization. If you don't know how to do that, it's a different question, and available on SO as well. I don't want to produce a duplicate answer

Comment: oh ok cool, so after i do that, how do i just create a localized string to replace the parse code with?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using logInWithUsernameInBackground method.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("testuser", password:"1234") {
    (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
            println("user login.")
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error",
                message: error.description, // or your message.
                delegate: self,
                cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
            alert.show()
        }
}
```

Comment: wait so where exactly do i plug in my custom message? and this still doesn't alter the parse clouds authentication checking correct? meaning it will still check if user parameters are legit, but just spew out my own message